# LIBCURL win32 static with SSL

Tags: openssl, libcurl

I want to have a LibCurl that is Static-link with Win32 and HTTPS support
can anyone tech me about how to compile this?
or send me the compiled file to my email

Comment: email:mapleelyse@outlook.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out that when I go to http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and under Source Archives download the source files and then I can find VS project from VC6 to VC12 in libcurl/projects/windows/ and then select the project config I can find all kind of curl I want.

Answer (score 2):

libcURL for Win32 is here http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w32/curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32.zip, the cURL exec binary for Win32 is here http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w32/curl-7.40.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-idn-static-bin-w32.zip

Comment: hmm I think since this is for mingw32 so it doesn't work for VS2013?